# How do I do this with one regular expression pattern instead of three?

Tags: c#, regex

I think I need to use an alternation construct but I can't get it to work. How can I get this logic into one regular expression pattern?

```
match = Regex.Match(message2.Body, @"\r\nFrom: .+\(.+\)\r\n");
if (match.Success)
    match = Regex.Match(message2.Body, @"\r\nFrom: (.+)\((.+)\)\r\n");
else
    match = Regex.Match(message2.Body, @"\r\nFrom: ()(.+)\r\n");
```

EDIT:

Some sample cases should help with your questions

```
From: email
```

and

```
From: name(email)
```

Those are the two possible cases. I'm looking to match them so I can do

```
string name = match.Groups[1].Value;
string email = match.Groups[2].Value;
```

Suggestions for a different approach are welcome!
Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your expressions? Especially the third one what is `()` good for?

Comment: How do you plan on using the match?  Probably use the first and second groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is literally what you're asking for: `"(?=" + regex1 + ")" + regex2 + "|" + regex3`

```
match = Regex.Match(message.Body, @"(?=\r\nFrom: (.+\(.+\))\r\n)\r\nFrom: (.+)\((.+)\)\r\n|\r\nFrom: ()(.+)\r\n");
```

But I don't think that's really what you want.

With .net's Regex, you can name groups like this:  `(?<name>regex)`.

```
match = Regex.Match(message.Body, @"\r\nFrom: (?<one>.+)\((?<two>.+)\)\r\n|\r\nFrom: (?<one>)(?<two>.+)\r\n");

Console.WriteLine (match.Groups["one"].Value);
Console.WriteLine (match.Groups["two"].Value);
```

However, your `\r\n` is probably not right.  That would be a literal `rnFrom:`.  Try this instead.

```
match = Regex.Match(message.Body, @"^From: (?:(?<one>.+)\((?<two>.+)\)|(?<one>)(?<two>.+))$");

Console.WriteLine (match.Groups["one"].Value);
Console.WriteLine (match.Groups["two"].Value);
```